# Order to save OneToMany relationship with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have these two beans:

```
public class AgentSubscription {

//...
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy = "subscription")
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
  @OrderBy("ID_SUBSCRIPTION")
  private List<OutputChannel> channels;
//...
}
```

and

```
public class OutputChannel {
//...
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SUBSCRIPTION", nullable = false)
  private AgentSubscription subscription;
//...
}
```

If we try to use this method:

```
  @Transactional
  public void addChannel(AgentSubscription subscription, OutputChannel channel)
  {
    try
    {
      List<OutputChannel> channels = new ArrayList<OutputChannel>();
      channels.add(channel);
      subscription.setChannels(channels);
      subscription = agentSubscriptionDao.insert(subscription);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      LOGGER.error("Unable to add channel to subscription " + subscription.getSubscriptionId());
    }
  }
```

We get this exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.domain.agent.beans.channel.OutputChannel.subscription
```

Shouldn't Hibernate save the subscription before the channel? Could it be a problem with the  CascadeType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to set the `subscription` in the `channel` object, which references it and the value is not nullable. That is the cause of the exception you recieved. This type of mapping creates `AgentSubscription` foreign key in the `OutputChannel` table, so you always have to set it, cascading or not. Hibernate does not perform any autosetting or some sort of that.
So in terms of your code, adding

```
channel.setSubscription(subscription);
```

before DAO insert call should solve the issue. This way when `entityManager.persist(subscription)` (or however you persist) is called, the `channel` will be persisted too.